# Should one avoid constructor use for field initialization in PHP?

Tags: php, constructor

I just had a talk with two colleagues yesterday, who told me that I should stop using constructors for field initialization in PHP.

Their reasoning was that if instances of the class would be created in different places and I decided to add another constructor parameter, all places where that class is instantiated would need to be updated with the new parameter. This would be tight coupling so to speak

I am quite new to PHP and in C# I would use the constructor and just do this:

```
public class Example 
{
    public int X { get; set;}
    public int Y { get; set;}

    public Example(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

}
```

Now I add another parameter by overloading the existing constructor:

```
public class Example 
{
    public int X { get; set;}
    public int Y { get; set;}
    public int Z { get; set;}

    public Example(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public Example(int x, int y, int z) : this(x, y)
    {
        Z = z;
    }

}
```

Doing it like this wouldn't require any change to existing code, right?

As far as I know PHP does not have constructor overloading like C# or Java. Is that the reason why one should avoid constructor use in PHP?

Any ideas on the topic are appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why someone would say constructors in that sense, they are quite common for doing DI.  Perhaps they mean you should have separate methods to set values, but then some objects are meaningless without those values.

Comment: In C# you can use factory pattern which encapsulate "creating process" and then you have only to change factory when you update constructor. I am not sure how it is in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to write classes and achieve *quite the same* is to use private fields with getters/setters, and setters being able to chain (they returns `$this`)

This could be done this way :

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    private $a;
    
    public function GetA() { return $this->a; }
    
    public function SetA($a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
        
        return $this;
    }
    
    private $b;
    
    public function GetB() { return $this->b; }
    
    public function SetB($b)
    {
        $this->b = $b;
        
        return $this;
    }
    
    private $c;
    
    public function GetC() { return $this->c; }
    
    public function SetC($c)
    {
        $this->c = $c;
        
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function ToString()
    {
        return "{$this->a} {$this->b} {$this->c}" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

---

Usage

```
$foo = (new Foo())
        ->SetA("Hello")
        ->SetB("World")
        ->SetC(42);

echo $foo->ToString();
```

---

This outputs

```
Hello World 42
```

Comment: Thank you, that answer looks good, but how do you make sure that the required fields were set when calling a method that needs them?

Comment: @Florian Well, you can use [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of those topics where you can discuss for a million years and still have a million different views on it. So I wont go into that (also SO is not the place for that). For a solution to the problem, php does allow for nullable paramaters. You could use something like this:

```
class Example {

    public $x;
    public $y;
    public $z; 

    public function __construct(int $x = null, int $y = null, int $z = null) {
        if ($x) {
            $this->x = $x;
        }

        if ($y) {
            $this->y = $y;
        }

        if ($z) {
            $this->z = $z;
        }
    }

}
```